# import mp4 file in blender

Tags: blender, mp4

I installed blender to edit my videos with mp4 format, but when I started import files blender show me this error : "file could not be loaded"! I don't know what's the problem here! is a codec video missing ??
any one can help me please

Answer (score 1):

It looks like blender in Ubuntu is missing ffmpeg. I have the same problem and the recommended solution is to [download the binary version](https://builder.blender.org/download/) in the official site.

I did it and it worked for me. I'd also like to know how to make Ubuntu's blender package to work mp4 files.

Here is where I got the [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28839/cannot-load-movie-files-on-ubuntu).